# wooCommerce pagination do not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I setup wooCommerce site and default pagination is enabled. But it is not working as expected.

It shows three pages where third page is coming blank. Also sometimes on second page two product's block are empty and those products are appearing on third page. Ideally these two products must come on second page.

I also added [WOOF - WooCommerce Products Filter plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/) for filter.
Am I missing any settings? Can anyone help me to sort this.

Comment: woocommerce pagination not working when using ajax time?

Comment: First of all you should tell me have you done any modification or is this issue come at your custom page? You must share code if you did any customization.

Comment: Please use shortcode something like that if ajax is calling [woof is_ajax=1 taxonomies=product_cat:9,12+locations:30,31] read about plugins features Shortcode&Widget -> [woof], described here
Products shortcode [woof_products per_page=8 columns=3 is_ajax=1 taxonomies=product_cat:9]

Comment: after added only this booster-plus-for-woo-commerce plugin in that plugin i have enabled product by country module then pagination and count not working properly. all other filter plugins it working fine.